# How to retain Laravel 5 selected local language?

Tags: php, laravel, localization

For example, I log in and selected `en` as my language and then I select `zh` (chinese) and then log out. Is there any way to retain the localization after you log-out the app?

this is the way I implement locale.

web.php:

`Route::post('change-locale', 'LocaleController@changeLocale')->name('change.locale');`

LocaleController:

```
class LocaleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function changeLocale(Request $request) {

        $this->validate($request, ['locale' => 'required|in:' . implode(',', config('app.available_locales'))]);

        Session::put('locale', $request->input('locale'));

        return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

Logout:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        $locale =  session('locale');
        $locale = Session::put('locale', $locale);
        Session::flush();
        //$request->session()->invalidate();
        //$request->session()->put('locale',$locale);
        return redirect('/login');
    }
```

Locale Setting:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Session::has('locale')) {
            $locale = Session::get('locale', Config::get('app.locale'));
        } else {
            $locale = substr($request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'), 0, 2);

            if (!in_array($locale, Config::get('app.available_locales'))) {
                $locale = 'en';
            }
        }        
        App::setLocale($locale);

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: please provide more information, how are you setting the locale?

Comment: updated the criteria

Comment: you can try to use cookies for that, i think?

Comment: hmm. great idea. but i was thinking if i can put it into a LocalStorage in jquery?

Comment: that's ok too, but you need to setup your own implementation or if you already have references for implementation. In Laravel you just have to get the cookie via `Cookie::get()`. depends on you. :D

Comment: cool. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you into session then that value you can get through

```
$locale =  Session::get('locale');
Session::flush();
Session::set('locale',$locale);
```

what i do, i use session global helper for get session value you can get any where this value

Comment: but I saw in my log out, I'm deleting all the sessions in laravel. is there a way where i will not delete the 'locale' ?

Comment: yes this is possible you can forget all the session value but avoid only locale i write code for you

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: I tried your code. looks like it is the correct way, but after I log out and redirect to log in screen, all the sessions are gone..

Comment: I put also how to set my locale

Comment: Session::flush(); write this on position last third line and its work :)

Answer (score 2):

I do it this way in Laravel 6:

Add to /app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php
this two functions:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $locale =  Session::get('locale');
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    return $this->loggedOut($request, $locale) ?: redirect('/');
}

protected function loggedOut(Request $request, $locale)
{
    Session::put('locale',$locale);
}
```

and this uses:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;
```

Comment: This is exactely what I needed and it works like a charm with Laravel 7! Thanx !